# Who killed Alice?

Tags: pandora-hearts

In anime we are not told who killed Alice, but I'm sure it does in the manga, so I want to know who the real killer is. In the *Pandora Hearts* anime, Vincent Nightray was there when Alice was killed. Does it make him the suspect in Alice's death?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one killed her. Alice committed suicide

> When Jack was trying to get Oz (B-Rabbit) to destroy the world

From the [Alice/History Page](http://pandorahearts.wikia.com/wiki/Alice/History) of the wikia:

> Alice worried as she could feel the danger of the situation sinking in, and so she grabbed a pair of scissors off of the table nearby ... Suddenly Alice plunges the scissors into her chest, commiting suicide to prevent the Intention from being able to take over her body and give [B-Rabbit] more power to destroy the world.

Of course this is only stated in the manga as the anime only really goes into detail with the connection between Alice and the Intention of the Abyss and does not show what truly happened during the Tragedy of Sablier or the real perpetrator.

In [Vincent's History](http://pandorahearts.wikia.com/wiki/Vincent_Nightray/History), during the Tragedy of Sablier it states that he arrived after Alice died before running to find Gilbert. The part in the anime where Break is with the Intention and she is breaking down when Vincent showed up is after Sablier had fallen into the Abyss and Alice was already dead.

The pages listed will contain heavy spoilers as the anime only stops part-way and I think the last two episodes actually deviate from the manga — at least the Wikia says in the trivia for [*Episode 24 - Kyrie*](http://pandorahearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kyrie) that it is filler.

> This epsisode is to say that this is a filler. This never happen in the manga thus making it a filler.